# Pass List<objects> to the jQuery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass the List to my jquery function in asp.net mvc application, and want to itterate it in jquery function. what i have to do.

**Edited: Added my code here**

Script:

```
 $.getJSON('/LoadTest/GetAllQuestionsForTest', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function() {

                    alert("hi");
                });
            });
```

controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult GetAllQuestionsForTest()
        {
            int testId = 1;
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(testId);
            List<Question> questionList;

            questionList = questionManager.GetquestionsByTestId(id);
            return Json(questionList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Is JSOn only the way there. i am unable to get Json and its processing. please guide

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize your list to a JSON object and then loop through it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.YourList) %>;
    $.each(list, function(index, element) {
        // TODO: Do something with the element.
    });
</script>
```

Another possibility is to fetch this list in an AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("GetMyList") %>', function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(index, element) {
            // TODO: Do something with the element.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what should be the action returns for first possibility?

Comment: unable to resolve the used classes in this line : var list = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.YourList) %>;
Means i am not getting Model there . any any namespace i need to import there?

Comment: @Lalit, you the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class is defined in the  `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace of the `System.Web.Extensions.dll` assembly.

Comment: oh. but it is included in my app reference. i am getting error while serializing View data, that having the List<Question> . Error :A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'MyTestApp.Models.Question'. error , any idea about this .

Comment: @Lalit, objects with circular references cannot be serialized. You might need to remove those circular references. A good way to do this is to use a view model.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a JsonResult from your MVC action.

```
List<MyObject> myList = /* get the data */

return Json(myList);
```

This assumes that you're object will serialise nicely without any complications. If the object is complex you may want to serialize it yourself with a JavaScriptSerializer and return a Content action result.

Another serialiser you may want to look at would be [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is Javascript in the end, it can't understand CLR types and so many formats can be applied on your data (Objects at hand) like serializing them to JSON so the jQuery at the client side can understand it.

for JSON, [HERE](http://www.jsonlint.com) is this so beneficial website to validate your JSON notation to make sure it is valid and represented correctly.

Comment: yaaa. I am getting "syntax error, unexpected TINVALID at line 1
Parsing failed" what does it means. not getting exact syntax error by your link.

Comment: @Lalit Well it is a validator, not a compiler. But though you may consider this a deficiency in it, but it is a very famous validator. My analysis: you have an error in your quotes/double-quotes arrangement, could you post the generated JSON or a decent sample of it so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

In your MVC application, you can result a JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult MyAction()
{
    var myList = GetMyList();
    return Json(myList);
}
```

Then in jQuery, you can call your controller as an AJAX request and iterate though them:

```
$.getJSON('/Controller/MyAction',function(data){
   $.each(data, function(){
        console.log(this);
   });
});
```

Example: http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: not getting any data, i can see, it is calling the required action but unable to fetch data.please see question again, i have edited my code

Comment: @Lalit - My example was really to point to in the right direction. Could you please post the JSON you get if you just go to http://yoursite.com/LoadTest/GetAllQuestionsForTest in your browser

Comment: well how can i see my json data , so that I can post you

Comment: Open the action in your browser, just as you would with any ViewResult action. It should output the JSON to your browser window.

Comment: yes , go it. this is my json data:[{"QuestionId":2,"QuestionText":"Question 1","TopicId":1},{"QuestionId":3,"QuestionText":"Question 2","TopicId":1}]. is it generating wrong vbalues

Answer (score 0):

You can return a JsonResult from the action method like :

```
return new JsonResult{Data= lstObjects}; // lstObjects is the collection/list of objects.
```

And then to iterate you can take help of `$.each(...)` function or noraml `for{}..` loop. But $.each(...) will give you better performance over large collections.